# How can generate a base64 and inline SVG in same project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, webpack, base64

I working on a big project, and we have always use base64 svg and we called them into background-image for example.

So now, we want to use base64 and Inline SVG in React APP, so I can't find a good solution, because I can't use two different loaders.

Do you have some any advice for this use case ?
Or if you have any example.

Please take a look of my webpack config :

```js
const jsonLoaderRule = {
  test: /\.json$/,
  loader: 'json-loader'
};

const jsLoaderRule = {
  test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: [{
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query: {
      cacheDirectory: true
    }
  }]
};

const filesLoaderRule = {
  test: /.(ttf|otf|eot|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
  use: [{
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[name].[ext]',
      outputPath: 'fonts/',
      publicPath: './'
    }
  }]
};

/* This part for converting SVG into base64 */
const svgImageLoaderRule = {
  test: /\.(svg)$/,
  oneOf: [{
    loader: 'svg-url-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[name].[ext]',
      outputPath: 'svg-images/',
      publicPath: './'
    }
  }]
};
/* END */

/*

I have this, for convert SVG into inline SVG, but he doesn't work with constante above, it's logic, but I can't find a good solution. 

const svgImageLoaderRule = {
  test: /\.(svg)$/,
  loaders: [
    'babel-loader',
    {
      loader: 'react-svg-loader',
      query: {
        jsx: true
      }
    }
  ]
};
*/

const imagesLoaderRule = {
  test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'url-loader',
      query: {
        limit: 10000,
        name: '[name]-[sha512:hash:base64:7].[ext]',
        publicPath: './'
      }
    }
  ]
};

const rules = [
  jsonLoaderRule,
  jsLoaderRule,
  imagesLoaderRule,
  svgImageLoaderRule,
  filesLoaderRule
];

module.exports = rules;
```

Comment: Hi. I am wondering if you guys found a solution for this, I am facing the exact same problem as well.